# I'm trying to debug a mergesort program that I wrote to sort binary input files

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-errors, gdb, mergesort

*FIRST TIME POSTING* I'm trying to debug a program that reads an input file, copies its values to an array, sorts the array using mergesort, and then writes that sorted array to an output file. I've reached the point where my makefile will compile the code without any warnings or errors, but will not create an output file for any of the test cases. I am 99% sure that my makefile is set up correctly. So, I figured that I would use gdb to try and gain any more details about the problem but when I set a breakpoint in any of the functions and try to run, it exits with code 01. I suspect this has something to do with main, but I have no idea where to start modifying code without any more details. I also think that think that the error could occur when trying to read the values and store them in an array, or when trying to write to the output file at all. That being said, I've written everything to the best of my ability and I've spent some time here searching for a solution.

The code is being run in an ssh shell, so I don't have access to anything administrative, and I shouldn't need to. The error has to be within my code. The necessary libraries and headers are not shown but are guaranteed to be correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as well as any explanation as to why I am doing something wrong as I would like to make as few future mistakes as possible.

```
int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
        // argv[1]: name of input file (binary)
        // argv[2]: name of output file (binary)
        if (argc != 3)
        {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int arrsize;

        bool rtv;
        rtv = readData(argv[1], &arr, &arrsize);

        if (rtv == false)
        {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        mergeSort(arr, 0, arrsize - 1);

        rtv = writeData(argv[2], arr, arrsize);
        free(arr);

        if (rtv == false)
        {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

_____________________________________________________________________

bool readData(char * filename, int * * arr, int * size)
{

        FILE * filepointer;
        filepointer = fopen(filename, "rb"); // open file for reading binary

        if (filepointer == NULL)
        {
                return false;
        }

        if (fseek(filepointer, 0 , SEEK_END) != 0) // put filepointer at the end of the file
        {
                fclose(filepointer); // check whether failed 
                return false;
        }

        int filesize;
        filesize = ftell(filepointer); // get filesize

        if (fseek(filepointer, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) // bring filepointer back to beginning of file
        {
                fclose(filepointer);
                return false;
        }

        int numint;
        numint = (filesize / sizeof(int)); // find number of integers in array

        int * mergearr  = malloc((sizeof(* mergearr)) * numint); // allocate an array to use for mergesort

        if (mergearr == NULL) // check whether allocation fails
        {
                fclose(filepointer);
                return false;
        }

        int numint2;

        if (fread(&numint2, sizeof(int), 1, filepointer) != numint)
        {
                fclose(filepointer);
                return false;
        } 
        else
        {
                fclose(filepointer);
        }

        * arr = mergearr; // update argument for array address

        * size = numint2; // update size of array

        return true;
}

________________________________________________________________

bool writeData(char * filename, const int * arr, int size)
{

    FILE * filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen(filename, "wb");

    if (filepointer == NULL)
    {
            return false;
    }

    if ((fwrite(arr, sizeof(int), size, filepointer) != size))
    {
            fclose(filepointer);
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
            return true;
    }

}

__________________________________________________________________

static void merge(int * arr, int l, int m, int r)
{

    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int LeftSize = m - l + 1;
    int RightSize = r - m;


    int * Left = malloc((sizeof(* Left) * LeftSize)); // Array allocation
    int * Right = malloc((sizeof(* Right) * RightSize));;

    for (i = 0; i < LeftSize; i++) // Copying over elements 
    {
            Left[i] = arr[l + i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < RightSize; j++)
    {
            Right[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0; // Reset indices
    j = 0;
    k = l;

    while (i < LeftSize && j < RightSize) // Merge arrays back together
    {
            if (Left[i] <= Right[j])
            {
                    arr[k] = Left[i];
                    i++;
            }
            else
            {
                    arr[k] = Right[j];
                    j++;
            }
            k++;
    }

    while (i < LeftSize) // Copy leftover elements
    {
            arr[k] = Left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
    }

    while (j < RightSize)
    {
            arr[k] = Right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
    }
}

____________________________________________________________________

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{

    if (l < r)
    {
            int m;
            m = l + (r - l) / 2;

            mergeSort(arr, l, m);
            mergeSort(arr, m+l, r);

            merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with, you're only reading one number from the file and you don't store it in the array.

Comment: where am I only reading one number? if you're talking about the last fread call in the readData function I was trying to read the number of integers in the file to  make sure it was the same as the number that I calculated using fseek and ftell

Comment: @amateurhour There's only one `fread` call, and it's not in a loop.

Comment: wait do I need a loop for fread to tell me how many integers are in a file?? fread is only supposed to read the binary file and tell me how many integers there are, writeData is supposed to write the values from the file into the array using the looped fwrite call. The array is then supposed to be split and copied into two temporary arrays and sorted, and then I write the sorted array to the ouput file in main, the output file being argv[2]. at least that's how the progression goes in my head

Comment: Please show us *how* you invoke the program in GDB, and where you set breakpoints. I suspect you don't supply two arguments, and so the program takes the `if (argc!=3)` exit.

Comment: Try to debug your program right with the first statement. Then you'll see where the error occurs. And, BTW, your source is not compileable, for example `arr` is not defined and gets no allocated memory and the includes are missing, please provide a [example].